# C# WorkerService / Design Pattern / Tutorials

Tags: c#, service

i apologize for my bad English.

yesterday, I learned that the new to create services is with Worker Services (for heavy workload).

Well I researched a lot and watched some videos and there are still some questions that i can't answer nor found a hint.

I stumbled over article (https://www.telerik.com/blogs/getting-started-worker-services)

My Use-Case is that I want to create a Windows service that uses Sockets to communicate with clients. The service should communicate with all clients and execute heavy tasks.
(I found out how I can do this, that's not the problem).

My Questions are (related to the link above):

1. In The Program.cs Class, there is a method AddTransient <-- What is it used for?
2. Also in the Program.cs Class, there is a method AddDbContext <-- Which types of databases can i use there? only sqlite?
3. AddHttpClient in the Program.cs Class <-- If i add the class there and not initalize it in Worker what is the benefit of this?
4. AddHostedService <-- Does this mean that the Service will execute the Worker-Class or something like that?
5. In the worker-Class there is the Field ILogger (i assume that this is used for logging) and UserEqualizerService is a service that executes stuff. Why is it only readonly? Why does the Worker get through his constructor the UserEqualizer? And how does the UserEqualizer gehts the PlaceHolderClient und UserDbContext.
6. Has this whole Service a Design Pattern (maybe you know the name if there is)? And maybe you know some good sources where i can find an easy explanation of this.
7. I assume that UserEqualizerService is a service itself. can i create multiple services (DummyService...) and can i just add in Program.cs in the Method AddTransient the Service?
8. Is the folder structure in the sample project best practice or do you know a better way?

I thank you guys in advance i really would love to understand this topic.